# What is Impedance Mismatch?

Tags: sql, database

What is "Impedance Mismatch" and how does it relate to databases?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Quoted from [hacked.com](http://haacked.com/archive/2004/06/15/impedance-mismatch.aspx/)

> Imagine you have a low current flashlight that normally uses AAA
>   batteries. Don't try this at home, but suppose you could attach your
>   car battery to the flashlight. The low current flashlight will
>   pitifully output a fraction of the light energy that the high current
>   battery is capable of producing. Likewise, if you attached the AAA
>   batteries to Batman's spotlight, you'll also get low output. However,
>   match the AAA batteries to the flashlight and they will run with
>   maximum efficiency.
>
> So taking this discussion back to software engineering, if you
>   imagine the flow of data to be analogous to a current, then the
>   impedance of a relational data model is not matched with the impedance
>   of an object hierarchy. Therefore, the data will not flow with maximum
>   efficiency, a result of the impedance mismatch.

Comment: If you put a 12V car battery to a flashflight that normally runs on 1.5V it will literally flash and burn out (as 64 times more power flows through it). Whoever wrote that quote didn't know much about electricity.

Comment: Flashlights often use more than one battery, which increases the voltage, although admittedly 8 AAA batteries would be unusual.

Comment: Also seems silly to pull in an electrical engineering concept just to confuse a far simpler software concept.

Comment: You have to explain impedance, then give an example of a circuit with mismatched impedance while knowing nothing about EE (by the way, this example is not what impedance mismatch is), then analogise a data model to a circuit (which already makes little sense), then somehow stretch the analogy to fit the already inappropriate term...

Normally an analogy uses a simple/everyday concept to explain something more complex. Are you teaching programming to electrical engineers?

Answer (score 5):

Relational impedance mismatch is a set of technical difficulties appearing because objects or class definitions must be mapped to database tables defined by relational schema.

Concretely, initial versions of SQL were not computationally complete (they did not have any programming constructs like declarations or conditional statements) but nowadays you can embed SQL in high-level programming languages (Java, C, Python and so on).

And here comes the **impedance mismatch**. SQL is a declarative language while C (or whatever high-level programming language you chose to embed your SQL queries on) is a procedural language, leading to a mixing of approaches and requiring a huge amount of unnecessary effort.

For instance, SQL has the Date type and handles rows of data at a time while high-level programming languages might use different models to represent data (i.e might not have the Date type) and can handle only one row of data at a time.

We might consider extending SQL with procedural constructs (SQL/PSM = Persistent Stored Modules) to avoid impedance mismatching and to treat a table as a flat file that can be accessed one row at a time.

Answer (score 5):

> **Mismatches between two paradigms like the Object-Oriented world and Relational world are called Impedance Mismatch.**

*There are 5 Mismatches that are there...*

1) **Granularity:-** The number of classes and tables are sometimes different.
                 (in one table we are storing multiple class object data.)

2) **Subtype:-** Object-oriented world has an Inheritance relationship but the Relational database world doesn't support inheritance.

3) **Association:-** Object-oriented world has Association relationship but the Relational database world doesn't support Association.

4) **Identity:-** Identity of an object in an Object-oriented world and the identity of a record in the Relational database world are different.

5) **Data navigation:-** Object data can navigate through their object-reference but the table data can't navigate.

> **If any framework solves this Mismatch completely then that framework is called a perfect ORM framework.**

Answer (score 0):

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180123-00/?p=97865

In electrical engineering, an impedance mismatch occurs when the input impedance of an electrical load does not match the output impedance of the signal source, resulting in signal reflection or an inefficient power transfer (depending on the type of matching required).

That is not what it means at Microsoft.

In relational databases, an impedance mismatch occurs when a relational database needs to be transformed into an object-oriented model.