# What does "Impedance Mismatch" mean when it comes to mlir?

Tags: compilation, llvm

Some people say that: [MLIR](https://mlir.llvm.org/) is a great infrastructure for higher-level compilation, and it can reduce **impedance mismatch** at each level.

What does the compound term "Impedance Mismatch" mean exactly when it comes to mlir?

Answer (score 0):

A related answer on this topic is here, which is good context: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41017152/14457718

A common way that compilers work, such as in LLVM is that they will have a few well defined interfaces (IRs) that allow optimizations within that interface and complete transformations between them. For various reasons that I'll avoid in this post, a common decision is to keep as few IRs as possible and encourage everyone to compile to/from them.

The decision to have fewer IRs leads to a situation that any optimizations or concepts have less choices for which IR to represent the topic. Let's take loops for example. LLVM will represent this as lower level branch statements. This makes it much more difficult to combine/split/unroll loops, as you need to understand the original loop, given a sequence of branches. Note that this is not impossible; it's just more work and harder to debug due to the "Impedance Mismatch."

MLIR's claim to reducing impedance mismatch is that, for example, it supports IRs with loops, other IRs with branches, and other IRs with memory views. Given more IRs, any given topic is more likely to have an IR where the optimization is simple, rather than requiring first reconstructing conceptual information from a less fitting IR.

The list of dialects in the MLIR directory, just to show the larger number of options to represent topics: https://mlir.llvm.org/docs/Dialects/

Side notes that I am trying to answer related questions here, but you'll get much more prompt feedback from the community at these places:
https://discord.gg/xS7Z362
https://llvm.discourse.group/